# Bootstrap how to adjust columns dynamically during empty data

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

We are using bootstrap to display marketing data. We wanted to display as one column for small devices and 3 column for medium devices, which works.

### Issue with Medium devices:-

In below code snippet, few times, "Marketing Data1" might NOT exist. Now bootstrap adds empty column. How do we modify bootstrap such a way that if "Marketing Data1" does not exist, it should be only 2 columns with center for medium devices. My thought is, it cannot be achieved in bootstrap. If yes, please suggest a way close to bootstrap with some other methodology.

```
<code>
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">Marketing Data1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                <div class="marketing-red">
                    Marketing Data2
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">Marketing Data3</div>
        </div>
</code>
```

Comment: use Javascript or jQuery  to remove empty divs in DOM

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap can't handle removing that column when "Marketing Data1" is blank. You'll have to handle that in your server-side (PHP or whatever you are using), or with Javascript on your client-side.

Comment: Bootstrap can't handle the truth